# WPF - LINQDataContest class alternative in wpf

Tags: wpf, linq

There is `LINQDataContest` class in windowsform which is for working with LINQ, but in `wpf` I didin't find it.

I want to know, is there another class instead of 'LINQDataContest' or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;
```

Is the standard using to allow using LINQ,

Not sure what LINQDataContest is for